# Alamofire Swift 4 boring SSL

Tags: ios, swift, upload, alamofire

im doing some file uploads with Alamofire and Swift. That file its uploaded always correctly but i still have some errors in console. Do anyone know how to fix that?

I was searching for some soloution but nothing helps me.

My part of code looks like this:

```
Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(recordedAudio!, withName: "audiofile", fileName: "audio.caf", mimeType: "audio/caf")},
                     usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                     to:"https://www.example.com/test.php",
                     method:.post,
                     headers:["User Name": "Janis"],
                     encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                        switch encodingResult {
                        case .success(let upload, _, _):
                            upload.responseString { response in
                                debugPrint(response)
                            }
                        case .failure(let encodingError):
                            print(encodingError)
                        }
    })
```

error (like 20x same error while upload once):

```
2018-05-01 15:58:13.570235+0200 appName[4764:1555915] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_errorlog: line 2878 [boringssl_session_write] SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL(5): operation failed externally to the library
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spurious output from the system, there's nothing you can do about it.